# Remove query from URL .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql

So I have successfully removed the database query from the url with the following in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /page.php?page_url=$1
```

However, now every request goes to this page. This is creating problems:

(1) Page request's that don't exist go to this page instead of the error404.html, so I wrote in the page:

```
<?php if ($row ['page_url'] == '') { header( 'Location: http://www.mysite.com/error404.html' ); } ?>
```

(2) Other page query stripping doesn't work and redirects to the error404.html:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /database.php?database_url=$1
```

(3) Pages go to whichever RewriteRule comes first:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /page.php?page_url=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /database.php?database_url=$1
```

With the rewrites above, the database requests go to the "page.php" document, not the "database.php"

Comment: so... what do you want to do? how should rewrite logic know where to go?

Comment: Wrt (1): Redirecting the browser to an error document will cause a status code of the 300 group, not the 404 you intend to. You'll have to either generate both status code and error document from that php, e.g. by forwarding the file. Or you change your rewrite rule to not rewrite non-existant objects. The former is more flexible, as it also caters for people entering the rewritten form of the URL.